# Has a Mathematics Formulary been tried again?

Tags: math-history

At the beginning of the last century, the Italian mathematician Giuseppe Peano published a work (the *Formulario Mathematico*) which expresses in symbolic language a number of definitions and theorems to which demonstrations are attached.
More precisely it starts with elementary logic, continues with algebra results and ends with differential calculus.

> [image: factorial]
>
> As an example, after the definition of the factorial, Peano immediately states a result due to Pascal.

What I like in this kind of book is the purity of mathematics in the sense that no exercise or example disturbs the content. Ideally, it should cover the broad outlines of the major fields of mathematics.

To my knowledge, no work of this type has been done since then except for a few result booklets written by Bourbaki as an introduction to the areas of mathematics they wanted to develop. Is this really the case?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *formulary*?

Comment: A document presenting in an organized way formulas, thus in our case theorems.

Comment: To what extent? Whole of mathematics known today; unlikely. Even for a single field this is nearly impossible to accomplish. The closest you could get is to look in a standard references of particular fields.

Comment: I can't know how complete a form that I don't know exists is... In any case, I didn't think for a moment about regrouping all the mathematics but rather works to present the main results of the main areas.

Comment: This wasn't meant as critique of your question rather as asking for clarification what you've in mind when asking for a *Mathematics Formulary* (which is, IMO, not a good choice of words). Anyway, the Bourbaki books are actually the closest you'll get and I wouldn't call them *nothing substantial* taking into account how voluminous they're.

Comment: I did not say that Bourbaki's books were not substantial, I said that their fascicles were not. Because they are the closest to what I am looking for in the sense that they have no historical exposition nor exercise.
The choice of words is simply a translation of Peano's treaty: Formulaire Mathématique/Formulario Mathematico.

Comment: So in less fancy language, you're looking for texts which just give lots of (definitions and) theorems (with or without proofs included?) - ideally covering the "fundamental" results of some of the "main" topics of mathematics. Is that accurate?

Comment: Please don't take my objections too personally! I've only pointed out that I think your question (in its current form) is impossible to answer as it remains unclear *what exactly* you're looking for. I don't know the word *fascicles* which might have caused some further confusion and also the literal translation of *Formulaire Mathématique/Formulario Mathematico* might not be the perfect choice. Anyway, I do think your question is quite interesting but in its current form unanswerable.

Comment: Noah Schweber that's pretty accurate although it would be nice to add a notion of organisation.

Comment: @mrtaurho Don't worry your critiques are interesting. Well "fascicle" is the word used by the publisher and in the Wikipedia article, it is basically a booklet.

Comment: I vastly improved the question, thanks!

Comment: If you are looking for something which starts from pure logic and tries to build up mathematics from there, perhaps you would be interested in reading recent formalization attempts? There's been a big push lately to translate math into a language computers can understand, which is pure logical syntax. Reading the code is more involved than reading a book, but it's a contemporary project that is possibly related to your interests. Lots of theorems have been formalized in this way, but there's still a lot of work to do

Comment: Are you talking about a database of a proof assistant software? If yes, the major problem will be the lack of structure.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one has said it, I'm going to give the obvious answer:

The only other "formulary" that I know of is Whitehead and Russell's *Principia Mathematica*. In some ways it is a successor to Peano's work, though it focuses primarily on logic and developing the foundations of mathematics. Part of the reason for this is that proofs of more complex topics, like analysis, become absurdly long when written *Principia*'s symbolic language.

One other work that comes to mind which you might be interested in is Frege's *Begriffsschrift*. It predates Peano's work considerably, but makes extensive use of the symbols-definitions-theorems format you describe.

I would also recommend looking at the [Metamath](http://us.metamath.org/mpeuni/mmtheorems.html) proof database, which includes thousands of formal proofs derived from basic logical axioms.